# How to set property between two Custom Actions in InstallExecuteSequence

Tags: wix

I have two Custom Actions that install some software on a PC.

```
    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="SETUP1" >

        </Custom>

        <Custom Action="SETUP2" >

        </Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

The first CA installs the first software, but in some cases something goes wrong and the installation fails. I want to set a property like `FIRSTSETUPFAILED = "TRUE"` and then execute the second CA only if this property `FIRSTSETUPFAILED` is TRUE.

I tried to implement some CA that reads regedit + looks at a folder on the PC, then writes the property in session (`session["FIRST"] = "TRUE";`), but I can't write into session from deferred CA.

How can I pass some properties between two Custom Actions in `InstallExecuteSequence`? The first Custom Action does not throw exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for [CustomAction Elements](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/customaction.html) and the Property attribute. Then to use the inner text for the second [Custom Element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/custom.html).

So something like...

```
<Property Id="PASSINGPROPERTY"/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="SETUP1" />
    <Custom Action="SETUP2" >PASSINGPROPERTY</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<CustomAction Id="SETUP1" Property="PASSINGPROPERTY">
<CustomAction Id="SETUP2">
```

Beyond needing to add how you will run your two install parts in CustomActions. The above example will pass the declaired PASSINGPROPERTY property to the second custom action. Your first CustomACtion will need to set this property to 'True'. Then when it is time for the second part, it will check the property and if true, it will run the second part. If it is not true, then you will skip the custom action. You could also throw an error with the error attribute in the custom action if you would like to stop the install. A lot of cool options at your disposal.

Comment: The problem is that I can not pass set property in Custom Action "Setup1". I can only read properties from CA in deferred Custom Action